# USB used for programming

Tags: power-supply, usb, stm32

I am working on a design for an STM32F103.
I use a Micro USB-B connector (as you can see in the following picture).

[image]

Can I use this USB to program my STM32 or does it only supply the microprocessor with power?

[image]
*This would be the power supply with a regulator.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The USB port of your STM32F103 can mainly be used for two things:

- Provide power to the device
- USB communication in case your firmware implements it (be it a serial over USB, a custom protocol, ...)

The USB port can usually not be used to upload firmware, unless:

- Your firmware implements uploading a new version of the firmware (using a standard or custom protocol).
- You install a special bootloader (e.g. https://github.com/rogerclarkmelbourne/STM32duino-bootloader/tree/master)

Note that such a bootloader is in addition the built-in bootloader and uses part of the flash. It often requires special configuration of the firmware project. The one mentioned above is designed for the Arduino IDE. The first time, it must be uploaded through SWD or serial.

Also note that other STM32 MCU have built-in bootloaders that support USB natively.

Comment: does that mean when I first connect the Board via USB it only supply the board with power?

Comment: @Codo Does that mean, first I would use J5-Male-Pins with an ST-Link to upload the bootloader and can then upload the firmware, right?

Comment: @nanash1 - no you can use UART, CAN and I2C to program this micro

Comment: @Y-E-Quit Yes you need to have the bootloader and you can use SWD pins (+ debug probe) to program it.

Comment: So my schematic would work if I first upload the boadloader via the J5 and after that I can upload anything I want via USB?

Does someone know if there is already a design for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, your schematic should work. What kind of design are you looking for? What should it achieve?

Comment: I look for another alternative for directly programming the STM32F103 via an Micro-USB. 

But if the alternative you mentioned, by uploading the boot loader via ST-Link (via SWDIO and SWCLK) is the best and easiest alternative, then I don't need any other solution. 

What do you mean?

Comment: A more common approach is to add a boot mode selection button and a USB-to-serial converter chip and upload the firmware that way. This is covered by the built-in bootloader. It's difficult to just what the best option is for your intended use case.